# C# WPF Binding a 2 RadioButtons conforme um boolean

Tags: c#, wpf

Boas pessoal.

```
<GroupBox Header="Tipo de operação" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="10,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296">
    <Grid x:Name="gridOperationType">
        <RadioButton x:Name="radioButtonPlus" Content="Acumulação" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="radioButtonChange" Content="Alteração" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Agora o que predentia era fazer um binding para ambos, se o bool estivese a verdadeiro para marcar o de cima ou se estivese a falso para marcar o de baixo

Para `TextBox` e afins é facil mas agora para esta situação não estou a conseguir encontrar nenhuma informação sobre isto.

Thanks

Comment: Uma dica, você poderia usar um `converter` para inverter o valor do `boolean` no `binding` de acordo com o que você quer. De uma olhada [aqui](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/). Você usaria ele e também poderia passar um paramêtro para diferenciar cada elemento, e sendo o radioButtonChange, você inverteria o valor do `boolean`. Para saber como usar o `ConverterParameter`, de uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6914124/8741188).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use o datatrigger a onde  `PropriedadeBool` é a propriedade boolean que você está verificando

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButtonPlus" Content="Acumulação" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropriedadeBool}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropriedadeBool}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>

<RadioButton x:Name="radioButtonChange" Content="Alteração" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropriedadeBool}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropriedadeBool}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>
```

Agora se você quiser fazer pelo codigo

```
public void NomeDoEvento(bool PropriedadeBool){
    radioButtonPlus.isChecked = PropriedadeBool;
    radioButtonChange.isChecked = !PropriedadeBool;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda :D esta porra já estava a dar comigo em maluco

Comment: kkk, que bom que funcionou